# is this no-op or something else?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>

int i;
int increment(int i)
{
    return ++i;
}

int main()
{
    for(i=0;i<10;increment(i))
    {
        printf("%d",i);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here output is 000000.  i.e. infinite lopp occurs.

I want to know that is this occuring due to no-op as we have no variable to store the value of ++i (returned by increment function) or it is due to something else? .please explain.

Comment: Compare with `for(i=0;i<10;i=increment(i))` and see [Call by Value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_value): "If the function or procedure is able to assign values to its parameters, only its local copy is assigned — that is, anything passed into a function call is unchanged in the caller's scope when the function returns." (Shadowing is also in place, it would be the same if the parameter in increment was `x`.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, it's a no-op. The call to `increment` doesn't change anything since the value is passed by value.

The local definition of `i` shadows the global definition. Therefore, only the local definition of `i` is used and the global definition of `i` is not affected by the increment which is done on the local copy of the variable.

Comment: @Mystical:you are saying that it is  a no-op because we are passing by value.Then why do when we write  for(i=0;i<10;i=increment(i)) ,then why does it print values from 0 to 10.

Comment: The function `increment` doesn't change the value of `i` due to shadowing and pass-by-value. However, it does return the new value. So if you assign it back to `i`, it will get incremented. If you don't assign it, nothing happens and `i` stays the same.

Answer (score 2):

The variable you are incremented is the local copy of the argument passed to increment. You have named both `i` so I may not be able to be so clear, but the point is that the `i` within `increment` is not the same than the one defined globally.